# How to save django FileField to user folder?

Tags: python, django, django-models, upload

I've got a model like this

> ```
> def upload_location(instance, filename):
>     return 'validate/%s/builds/%s' % (get_current_user(), filename) 
>
> class MidletPair(models.Model):
>     jad_file = models.FileField(upload_to = upload_location)
>     jar_file = models.FileField(upload_to = upload_location)
>     upload_to=tempfile.gettempdir()
> ```

How can I get the current user in upload_location()... ?

Side note:  Looking up django stuff is confusing as theres a lot of pre-1.0 stuff around on the net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current user is stored in the request object, and you can't get that in a model method unless you pass it in from elsewhere - which you can't do in the upload_to function.

So you'll need to approach this in a different manner - I would suggest doing it at the form level. You can pass the request object into the form's `__init__` method and store it in an instance attribute, where you can get to it in a custom upload handler. For documentation on upload handlers, look [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Comment: Cheers, I've just got this working... there could maybe more documentation on this - I had to dig into the django source (which was fairly readable), however as I'm still a django n00b this was a little scary.

Once I get my djangosnippets account sorted I'll upload it there, in the meantime heres a link to the custom class I made:
http://pastebin.com/f114b9d29

Comment: OK, this wasn't fully working (the form wasn't validating) - In the end I extended TemporaryFileUploadHandler to copy the file to the right location (in file_complete).  I'm still not sure why it's so hard to find info on this.

Comment: I only got part of this working, but the custom upload handler was saving stuff to the wrong place after .save was called... guess I need to learn more about django - for the moment I've given up on this, as I didn't get very far for quite a while on it.

Answer (score 5):

If you added a user field to the model, and have that attribute set before you performed an upload, then you could get the user in to your upload_location function via the instance attribute.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't search the net for Django help.  Search here only: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/

Second, the current user is part of Authentication.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#topics-auth

The user is recorded in the request.  `request.user`

Comment: The first point is good (and I did get into trouble doing this).  However as soon as you try and do something not covered in the django docs it leaves diving into the code as the next thing to do.